# Can't set UITextField's selectedTextRange if alert is presented, first

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm running the code below when the user has an input error.  If an error occurs, an alert is displayed and text in the UITextField is supposed to be selected.  If I run my alert function showErrorAlert() before selecting the text (as depicted below), the text is never selected.  If I comment out the alert function, the text selection seems to work fine (selecting the entire text in the input field).  I'm not sure what I need to do to get the selectedTextRange to select properly after calling my alert function.  Thanks for tolerating a n00b question.

// showErrorAlert Function

```
func showErrorAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

// When input error occurs…

```
    showErrorAlert(title: "ERROR", message: "Please type numbers, only.")

    inputText.becomeFirstResponder()
    let textBeginning = inputText.beginningOfDocument
    let textEnd = inputText.endOfDocument
    inputText.selectedTextRange = inputText.textRange(from: textBeginning, to: textEnd)
```

Comment: showErrorAlert method are on the same view controller???

Comment: Yes, both are part of the same view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your selection code inside the completion handler of your defaultAction. This way selection will take place *after* your user acknowledges and dismisses the alert. Like so:

```
func showErrorAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.textInput.becomeFirstResponder()
        let textBeginning = self.textInput.beginningOfDocument
        let textEnd = self.textInput.endOfDocument
        self.textInput.selectedTextRange = self.textInput.textRange(from: textBeginning, to: textEnd)
    }
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I just tested this on a device.

**Explanation**

When you call `present(alertController...)` what you are doing is presenting a *new* view controller modally. In your original code, you called `showErrorAlert` which then presents a new view controller (which in this case happens to be a UIViewController subclass called UIAlertController). That's totally fine.

But a problem occurs when you then--immediately after presenting this new view controller--try to select text in a UITextField that is not a subview of the currently presented view. A way to fix this is to call this selection code in the completion handler of your defaultAction. This ensures that your selection code will be executed only after the alert is dismissed and when your UITextField is back as a subview of the currently presented view.

Comment: This works great.  Any idea why it doesn't work outside the handler? I'm curious what I'm missing - it seems like the textField keeps some kind of focus if handled within the alert, even though it's not part of (and sits behind) the alert. Unsure why select doesn't work before or after alert call. Thx again!

Comment: I added an explanation. I hope this helps!